# Best way to select record with out IN operator in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called Sub_Router with below sample data and only two columns

Associated_Router_L1,Associated_Router_L2 both are composite primary key.

i want select all L2 Ronter id  for given L1 Routerid
for example if gave 2001 then result 2005,2006,2002,2007,2003,2008

My select sql is

Query - 1(With one level)

```
select s1.Associated_Router_L2 
from Sub_Router s1 
where s1.Associated_Router_L1 in (select s2.Associated_Router_L2 
                                  from Sub_Router s2 
                                  where s2.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001)
```

Query - 2(With two level)

```
select s1.Associated_Router_L2 
from Sub_Router s1 
where s1.Associated_Router_L1 in (select s2.Associated_Router_L2 
                                  from Sub_Router s2 
                                  where s2.Associated_Router_L1 in (select s3.Associated_Router_L2 
                                  from Sub_Router s3 
                                  where s3.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001))
```

Query-2 using Inner Join

select s1.Associated_Router_L2 from Sub_Router s1 INNER JOIN Sub_Router s2 ON s1.Associated_Router_L1 = s2.Associated_Router_L2 INNER join Sub_Router s3 on s2.Associated_Router_L1 = s3.Associated_Router_L2 where s1.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001 OR s2.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001 OR s3.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001

OR operation again creating a performace

Result coming fine, any better approach to avoid this IN,OR operator.

Table name: `Sub_Router` 
Column name: `Associated_Router_L1,Associated_Router_L2` both composite primary keys
Data as attached

```
Associated_Router_L1    Associated_Router_L2
                2000    2001
                2000    2002
                2000    2003
                2000    2004
                2001    2005
                2001    2006
                2001    2002
                2002    2007
                2002    2003
                2002    2008
```

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate the IN, when all works fine?

Comment: you can use INNER JOIN with same table with where clause. if any confusion let me know. i will provide the sample query. and it is better approach because IN with sub query is heavy then INNER JOIN.

Comment: Facing perfomance in live. can you share one sample for join pls

Comment: Here is the Query with One level select s1.Associated_Router_L2 
from Sub_Router s1 
INNER JOIN Sub_Router s2 ON s1.Associated_Router_L1 = s2.Associated_Router_L2
where s2.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001

Comment: when i try with level 2 then i need OR operator again        select s1.Associated_Router_L2 from Sub_Router s1 INNER JOIN Sub_Router s2 ON s1.Associated_Router_L1 = s2.Associated_Router_L2 INNER join Sub_Router s3 on s2.Associated_Router_L1 = s3.Associated_Router_L2 where s1.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001 OR s2.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001 OR s3.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001                                if i remove OR then missing some records So OR operator is require here. But OR operator again giving performance issue

Comment: Try this select s1.Associated_Router_L2 
from Sub_Router s1 
INNER JOIN Sub_Router s2 ON s1.Associated_Router_L1 = s2.Associated_Router_L2
INNER JOIN Sub_Router s3 ON s2.Associated_Router_L1 = s3.Associated_Router_L2
where s3.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sql might help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(s2.Associated_Router_L1, '-->', s2.Associated_Router_L2) branch
FROM Sub_Router s1, Sub_Router s2
WHERE
    s1.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001
    AND (s1.Associated_Router_L2 = s2.Associated_Router_L1 OR 2001 = s2.Associated_Router_L1)
```

If you want to go one lever deeper, add another table, expand the WHERE clause, and modify the SELECT fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(s3.Associated_Router_L1, '-->', s3.Associated_Router_L2) branch
FROM Sub_Router s1, Sub_Router s2, Sub_Router s3
WHERE
    s1.Associated_Router_L1 = 2001
    AND (s1.Associated_Router_L2 = s2.Associated_Router_L1 OR 2001 = s2.Associated_Router_L1)
    AND (s2.Associated_Router_L2 = s3.Associated_Router_L1 OR s1.Associated_Router_L2 = s3.Associated_Router_L1 OR 2001 = s3.Associated_Router_L1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL is not good at dealing with hierarchical / tree models.

Oracle for example has added `CONNECT BY ...` to support [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) as a non-standard extension

With standard SQL a typical approach to this is the '[Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)',
or you could use the [OQGraph storage engine](http://openquery.com.au/graph/doc) for MySQL / [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/oqgraph-storage-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not any faster, but at least will work to an arbitrary depth without needing to rewrite the query if/when your data or nesting depth changes.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Router_List  (
    Router int)

Declare @Input_Router int
Set @Input_Router = 2001

--Prime the pump
Insert into @Router_List (Router) Values(@Input_Router)

While (1=1)
Begin

    Insert into @Router_List (Router)
    Select Associated_router_L2
    From Sub_Router SR
    Inner Join @Router_List RL
    On SR.Associated_Router_L1 = RL.Router 
    Left Join @Router_List RL2
    On SR.Associated_Router_L2 = RL2.Router
    Where RL2.Router is Null

    --Till nothing to do
    If @@ROWCOUNT = 0 Break
End

Select * from @Router_List
```